# Trouble filtering out plural words

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have a table with the most frequent words in the English language which looks like this:

```
word count
cat 43534889
dog 34584357
hat 4343878
...
hats 44747
```

I'd like to exclude all the plural words like 'hats' if they already exist in singular form.

So I wrote this query

```
SELECT
  word,
  CASE WHEN CONCAT(word,'s') IN (
    SELECT freq.word from `words.freq` as freq
    WHERE freq.word LIKE '%s' AND LENGTH(freq.word) > 4
    )
    THEN 'plural'
    ELSE 'sing'
    END AS plural
FROM `words.freq` LIMIT 1000
```

My logic is: if the word 'hat' + 's' is found among words ending in 's' (subquery), it means it's just the plural form of that noun. Somehow the function CONCAT doesn't seem just to add 's' to each word, but it changes it so for example when I run this query, words like 'that' are somehow displayed as 'plural' as if they were longer than 4 characters and contained 's' at the end. I am really confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: One bus, several buses, etc. https://www.thoughtco.com/irregular-plural-nouns-in-english-1692634

Comment: @jarlh I understand that there're more cases than just words ending in 's' but I want to understand the logic of SQL in this query. Why can't it filter out words like 'hat' in ('hats')?

Comment: I guess that 'LENGTH(freq.word) > 4' is one of your conditions and 'hats' length is 4.

Comment: Isn't your logic the wrong way around? It should be something like `case when word in(select concat(freq.word, 's') ... then 'plural'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (in MySQL syntax) should do what you're looking for: as you say, this doesn't capture all the ways that English can make plurals, and it will also get some false positives ("hiss" would be considered as plural because "his" exists).

The idea is to look for words of >=4 characters ending in 's', and check whether the corresponding word with the final 's' removed exists:

```
SELECT word,
    CASE
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(word) >= 4 AND word LIKE '%s' AND LEFT(word, CHAR_LENGTH(word)-1) IN (SELECT word FROM words) THEN 'plural'
    ELSE 'singular'
    END AS plurality
FROM words;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment on my answer, I've totally forgot the "this" case. I went on the  same principle as you and it works perfectly ! ;-)

Comment: @slothrop I see what you did there and how it could potentially be useful, but I ran your query and it still returns every single word ending in 's' from the table... despite that last condition. I am very confused lol

Comment: @Eugene T here's an example: "hats" is shown as plural because "hat" exists, but "this" is shown as singular - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7fb42af0301217038e02321cd81303c7

Comment: @slothrop ok that does seem to work ;) at least with that sample. thanks

Comment: @Eugene T I guess you might get issues using large tables of uncleaned data.  For example if the word frequencies come from some big corpus of text, then it might be that "thi" appears somewhere as a typo, and so "this" is classified as plural.  Without knowing your exact data, I might suggest adding a WHERE clause to the inner SELECT to filter out words with very low frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can sort words in alphabetical descending order and compare a word with next word to check if it's singular form of it.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'cat' word, 43534889 count UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dog', 34584357 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'hat', 4343878 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dogs', 38738 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'hats', 44747
)
SELECT *,
       IF(CONCAT(LEAD(word) OVER (ORDER BY word DESC), 's') = word, 'plural', 'singular') is_plural
  FROM sample_table;
```

[image]

Comment: If you add the word "doggo" to the table, then "dogs" will be marked as singular because it's no longer adjacent to "dog" in alphabetical order.

Comment: @slothrop right, you made a point